# How to disable fast math for a header file function

Tags: c++, gcc, mathematical-optimization, pragma

How do I disable fast math for a function defined in header file or for the entire source file?

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("no-fast-math")
```

Adding the line above to both (source file and header file) doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: Note: Doing stuff like this in a header will infect all files that include the header. That can be an extremely nasty shock for the unwary.

Comment: The approach should be correct - https://godbolt.org/z/aTEmGQ. You should try to create minimal reproducible example and specify compiler version, command line arguments and why it seems does not working.

Comment: And it is indeed much safer to use such pragmas in combination with `GCC push_options` and `GCC pop_options` to always restore previous behavior so it does not  suddenly change depending on included files and the include order.

Comment: A piece of code which doesn't work when fast math is enabled can be seen in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938228/strange-while-loop-behavior