# Can this piece of code be modified such that it works with fast-math enabled?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, fast-math

Can the code below be modified such that it works correctly even when compiled by GCC with fast-math enabled?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char divider = 2;
  float power = 1;
  float number = 1;
  float current = number + power;
  cout.precision(20);
  // Divide until rounded off
  while(current != number)
  {
    power /= divider;
    current = number + power;
    //cout << current << endl;
  }

  cout << power * divider << endl;
  cout << FLT_EPSILON << endl;
}
```

Note: I have it in a header file and I haven't managed to turn off fast math for the header. See [Strange while loop behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938228/strange-while-loop-behavior) and [How to disable fast math for a header file function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941592/how-to-disable-fast-math-for-a-header-file-function)

Comment: What would you consider "correct" behavior?  What is actually the point of this code?

Comment: There are comments in your previous post about `cout.precision(1024)`; the C++ language does not have support for that much precision.

Comment: Just used random number. :-)

Comment: The "How to disable fast math" seems to have a solution in the comments: Use a GCC pragma to disable fast math and use push and pop pragmas so you don't mess it up for the rest of the code. Have you tried that?

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this piece of code into the loop solves the problem for me.

```
std::ostringstream buff;
    buff << current
```

Edit:

Even adding this into the condition works:

```
 && ! isinf(current)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn computation in constexpr function in constant expression:

```
constexpr float compute_epsilon()
{
  char divider = 2;
  float power = 1;
  float number = 1;
  float current = number + power;
  // Divide until rounded off
  while(current != number)
  {
    power /= divider;
    current = number + power;
  }
  return power * divider;
}
constexpr auto epsilon = compute_epsilon();
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84738fd7b95b35b3)

Comment: Is there something like that in C++98?

Comment: I don't think so. In addition, `float` value cannot be used as non-type template parameter.